# Search a string against another using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to check whether a String is contained in another String.

For example,  "abc" is contained in "abc/def/gh","def/abc/gh" **but not in**  "abcd/xyz/gh","def/abcd/gh".

So, I have split the `input` String by "/". Then iterated the generated String array to check against the `input`.

Is it possible to avoid the creation of the array using something like `Regex`?

Also, could anybody confirm whether using Regex will be faster than the creation & iteration of array as I have used?

Thanks in advance

```
public class RegexTest {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
          System.out.println(contains("abc/def/gh", "abc"));
          System.out.println(contains("def/abc/gh", "abc"));
          System.out.println(contains("def/abcd/gh", "abc"));
          System.out.println(contains("abcd/xyz/gh", "abc"));

     }

     private static boolean contains(String input, String searchString) {
        String[] strings = input.split("/");
        for (String string : strings) {
            if (string.equals(searchString))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
     }
 }
```

The console output is:
true
true
false
false

Comment: It also depends on the size of the array generated.

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
s.matches("^abc/.+|.+/abc/.+|.+/abc$")
```

or

```
   s.startsWith("abc/") || s.contains("/abc/") || s.endsWith("/abc")
```

Comment: clearly, the 1st argument(input) of contains() may not always be "abc".

Comment: this expr means starts with abc/ or has /abc/ in the middle or ends with /abc

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
String pattern = "(.*/)?abc(/.*)?";
System.out.println("abc/def/gh".matches(pattern));
System.out.println("def/abc/gh".matches(pattern));
System.out.println("def/abcd/gh".matches(pattern));
System.out.println("abcd/xyz/gh".matches(pattern));
```

prints

```
true
true
false
false
```

Comment: clearly, the 1st argument(input) of contains() may not always be "abc".

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I fully trust your Java skills to make the necessary adaptions.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex is more convenient (?), but please time yourself whether it is faster:

```
if (!searchString.contains("/")) {
    return input.matches("(.*/)?" + Pattern.quote(searchString) + "(/.*)?");
} else {
    return false;
}
```

I made sure that the `searchString` does not contain `/`, before inserting it as literal with [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29). The regex will make sure that there is a `/` before and after the search string in the input, either that or the search string is the first or last token in the input.